# Change the .NET version a website targets

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

There are two types of .NET projects i.e. websites and web applications.

With a web application you can specify what version of the framework you want to target by right clicking the project (under solution) and selecting properties.  Then selecting application.

How do you do this with ASP.NET websites? There does not seem to be a properties window.  Do you have to update the web.config manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010:

Right click on the web application "project", select Property Pages.

Click "Build" on the left, change "Target Framework" to the desired version.